# Performance tuning my update statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, optimization, sql-update

Hello I have to update my the qty in my database every night for a minimum of a 2 million parts. I am using jdbc as my mysql connector.

I am working with only 1 table a warehouse table.

We get sent in a file every night from each warehouse with the part number and the qty that needs to be updated.

here is the warehouse schema:

```
warehouse | CREATE TABLE `warehouse` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`sap_article_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`sap_warehouse` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
 `as400_warehouse` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `ds_warehouse` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `atp_qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `article` (`sap_article_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=497524962 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Warehouse indexes:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| warehouse |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id             | A         |     2858699 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| warehouse |          1 | article  |            1 | sap_article_id | A         |      571739 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

the warehouse table has about 3 million records in it.

I am unable to finish the processing of all these files during the night.

Here is my logic... like I said I have multiple files I need to process one for each warehouse.

```
"SELECT sap_article_id FROM " + WAREHOUSE_TABLE
                                + " WHERE " + "sap_article_id='" + sapArticleId
                                + "' AND sap_warehouse='" + sapWarehouse + "'";
```

if part exists at warehouse...

we update it..

```
  "UPDATE " + WAREHOUSE_TABLE + " "
                                    + "SET ds_warehouse='0'," + "atp_qty=" + atpQty
                                    + " WHERE sap_article_id='" + sapArticleId + "' AND "
                                    + "sap_warehouse='" + sapWarehouse + "'";
```

else if it doesn't exist we insert it...

```
"INSERT INTO " + WAREHOUSE_TABLE + "("
                            + "sap_article_id,sap_warehouse,as400_warehouse,ds_warehouse,atp_qty"
                            + ") VALUES ('"+sapArticleId+"'," + "'" + sapWarehouse
                            + "'," + "'" + as400Warehouse + "'," + "'0'," + "'"
                            + atpQty + "'" + ")";
```

Then we move onto the next line in the file and repeat.

Is there something I am doing wrong or something i can do to highly increase the speed of this process. Like I said earlier at this point it is taking way too long and I can't complete my task in the given time period. I have about 3-5 hours to be able to process all of this data and right now it is taking over 12 hours.

Comment: See INSERT ... UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: How are you handling transactions? Massive updates are typically faster if you do them all (or in blocks) within the same transaction. Another thing... instead of building the SQL statement for each record, you would be better off preparing two parametrized SQL statements (one for the update and one for the insert) and then executing them many times with the correct parameter values.

Comment: @Frazz i don't understand what you are saying when you say prepare two parametrized SQL statements.. can you give me a example.

Comment: Not in java actually. Anyway, something like UPDATE warehouse_table SET ds_warehouse='0', atp_qty=:apt_qty WHERE sap_article_id=:sap_article_id AND sap_warehouse=:sap_warehouse... This query has 3 parameters. You prepare it once, then you can execute it millions of times changing the parameters. The thing is that when you prepare it the server analyzes it and decides how to execute it. The value of the parameter don't really matter for the analysis. If you don't prepare it, then every single query you execute will be analyzed separately by the server before execution... and that is not good.

Comment: @Frazz and you are saying that i am not preparing it? it's the same query just changing the parameters every time... if i am not preparing it how do i go about preparing it.

Comment: Query preparation is done envolving the server. Most languages/frameworks have a construct/method for that, one to set parameter values, and another to execute the query. If you don't prepare the query, then most will do it implicitly on execution. For Java/JDBC, I suggest you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Frazz i just set this up and i am running the process now lets see how it runs. thank you.

Comment: still is taking forever to process 50,000 parts =( what else can i do?

Comment: actually i just restarted my server and things are running fast thanks mate!!

Comment: Never ever glue statements together the way you did unless you can completely ignore [security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are doing this RBAR, which is what I generally try and avoid like the plague.  Rather try and do a set based update like the below and then (if you have to) do a loop for the individual databases:

```
MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET column1 = value1 [, column2 = value2 ...]
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...
```

Comment: Works in Microsoft SQL, Oracle Database, DB2, Teradata, EXASOL and MS SQL.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert .  I have personally used it in MSSQL.

Comment: The attached Wiki article refers to the non-standard, but working, implementation of merge in MySQL (under the heading - Other non-standard implementations).